# get the creation time from core dump

Tags: c++, unix, solaris, coredump

I am working on a C++ application.
I got some core files from the client which he says are generated now but is not willing to say how are they generated and what he has done from generating them.

I think he is wrong and maybe he gave me the dump which was generated a long time ago.

Is there any way where I can get the actual creation time of the file?

I think the files may be created on some other servers and he has transferred them.
Is there a way to find out?

If it's not in the core file, maybe Unix has some way to know the actual creation time of the file in the current server or some other server.

Comment: I think the Solaris Crash Analysis Tool may help? https://blogs.oracle.com/solariscat/entry/oracle_solaris_crash_analysis_tool

Answer (score 3):

The creation time of the core file does not appear in the `core(4)` format in Solaris.

However, there are a couple of things you can do by looking at the `NOTES` section of the core (libelf to the rescue?). See `core(4)` for details.

First find the `NOTES` segment name (probably `note0` or (more likely) `note1`, no leading dot) with `objdump -x core`

#### Process start time

The `NT_PSINFO` entry contains a `psinfo_t` (see `<sys/procfs.h>`) which has a member `pr_start`. This is the start time of the process.

#### Zonename

Similarly, the zonename where the core was generated is in the `NT_ZONENAME` entry.

Since this is `char *` a quick and dirty way to do this, without parsing the segment, is just to dump'n'grep it:

```
objdump -s -j note1 core | grep ...
```

(`elfdump -n...` sounds useful but I couldn't get this to work).