# How can I get the system time from a core dump?

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, segmentation-fault, coredump

I have a core dump generated after a segmentation fault. Is there a way in gdb ( or somehow else ) to see the system time when this happened?

I cannot use the creation time of the core dump file because it was sent to me without this meta info.

Comment: I think that's pretty hard, unless you happen to know some variable somewhere that happens to contain current time. Next time, ask the customer to pack the file with `tar zcf core.tar.gz core` - then it takes less space and the timestamp is retained in the tar archive.

Comment: Related (but for Solaris): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739334/get-the-creation-time-from-core-dump

Comment: Given that most filesystems do not store creation time, it is not surprising that that information is unavailable.

Comment: Not a solution for your case, but maybe for others: if the originating system was running `systemd` and logging with `journald`, then it's possible to query the journal (on that system) with `systemd-coredumpctl` about the coredump.

Comment: Apparently, if the file   /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern  has '%t' in it, the file name of core will have the time in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The system time is (unfortunately) not stored in a core file by default. You have a couple of options. One of them is to change the name of the core file to include the system time.

You can read more about this [here](http://sigquit.wordpress.com/2009/03/13/the-core-pattern/).

Basically, you want to stick a "%t" into the name of the core file.

If you are running a custom kernel, you have more options.

For example, you could change the elf_prstatus structure to include other things you may want. This is an option that isn't without pain as off the shelf tools may not always be happy. You could add a custom note to the core file and include application specific information that you could then dump and inspect using readelf.

Answer (score 0):

Not answer as such but perhaps an answer in the future. http://stupefydeveloper.blogspot.co.nz/2008/10/gdb-examining-core-dumps.html

Answer (score 0):

They way i check when core dump is created by doing "ls -lrt" of the directory under which the core was generated.

Comment: And if the core file was copied from one place to another? The questioner says "I cannot use the creation time of the core dump file because it was sent to me without this meta info".

Comment: Yes my bad.. The only way to is to ask the customer to do the `ls -lrt` on the directory and send the coredump along. This is what we used to do in my old project.